# Generate Data + Invoke SSIS in same procedure, SSIS cannot reference generated data

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, stored-procedures, ssis

this should be a simple fix but I'm having a Process Brain Fart.  This is more of a process/order of operations problem than a coding problem.

I have a stored procedure that performs the following:

1. Accepts input from client application
2. Aggregates data together from different tables, does some string parsing
3. Stores results in a static table (Batch Table)
4. Calls InvokeSQLAgentJob procedure

The InvokeSQLAgentJob procedure fires off a job that runs an SSIS package which:

1. Reads some parameters from the static table (Batch Table)
2. Spins through records and dynamically creates a file system folder structure
3. Exports IMAGE data to the file system

Now, this process works if I run it in distinct steps.  I.E. I generate my Batch Table data and THEN run the SSIS package.  Trying to do it in an automated process is causing SSIS to not do anything, it appears that no matter what I do, the Batch Table data is COMMITTED until the procedure actually ends, even if I force commit the data inside the SP.

I know I'm running into something silly stupid regarding Transactions/scoping/control flow but not sure what else to try.  I could schedule the job, but the requirements are to have it "On Demand".  The process is instigated from a UI action on the front-end application.

Comment: I suspect (as you do) that there's something that SQL Server "doesn't like" between storing results in the Batch Table and calling the SQL job. What version of SQL Server are you running? If 2012 or later, you may consider replacing the SQL job with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj820152.aspx. If earlier, you could replace the call to the SQL job with a call to xp_cmdshell to invoke the SSIS package, provided access to xp_cmdshell isn't disabled (which it is by default).

Comment: The server is SQL 2012.  For security reasons I can't use xp_cmdshell, hence the launching of the SSIS job via an Agent job.

I looked at the new 2012 SSIS Catalog, but it's not configured on this particular server.  But, I'm not sure that would solve the problem.  Regardless of where it's living when executed, I don't think it'll solve the issue of my transactions not appearing committed before the package runs.

Comment: By `InvokeSQLAgentJob` do you mean sp_start_job or is there some homegrown thing you're referencing?

Comment: sp_start_job.  I think in the end I've convinced the business user to accept a scheduled run instead of being on-demand.  This should resolve the issue, but isn't the ideal implementation.  I've given up trying to work out the isolation level that's preventing it all from happening in one step.